# mySQL multi-dimensional (multi-user)

Tags: mysql, database-design

I am new to mySQL and database design. I think my previous attempt at explaining was confusing, so here is an image to help:

[image]

I have an mySQL database. Different users need to access the database and when they login stored information specific to them gets loaded into an n x m (6 x 7) table. Furthermore, they may select the "month" they want to view, each month is essentially different data loaded into the 6 x 7 view.

Questions:

1) Do I have a different database per user (there could be 1000's) or how do I arrange/manage the user/data access if it is just one database?

2) How do I manage/structure the "Months" or the Z-dimension, as my understanding is that mySQL are flat arrays.

Thanks.

[Ignore my clumsy explanation below]

> The requirement I have is to have an n x m table where n is a date
>   entry and m may be 1 to nth columns containing data about a user
>   specific to that date - weather, food, clothes. However, I then want
>   this format/table for 1 to nth users, so each user has there own page
>
> So for user 1 the table may look like:
>
> ```
> 06-04-15; sunny; apple; jeans
> 07-04-15; rainy; orange; coat
> 08-04-15; snow; mango; vest
>  for user 2 the table may look like:
>
> 03-04-15; sunny; apple; jeans
> 04-04-15; rainy; orange; coat
> 05-04-15; snow; mango; vest
> 06-04-15; wind; apple; hat
> 07-04-15; dry; bread; scarf
> 08-04-15; snow; mango; vest
> ```
>
> 1) I wondered if this is kind of structure is possible?
>
> 2) and whether it is the recommended way of structuring a user
>   database of this type?
>
> 3) Furthermore, the database rows may be growing more one user
>   instance, but not all users equally, would this cause problems?
>
> Any examples, tutorials or code snippets would be welcomed.

Comment: Unrelated to the questions but (not so) silly comment, about dates: `03-04-15` Is that `3-April-2015`? Or `March-4-2015`? Or `3-April-1915`? Or `2003-April-15`? Or ...?  There is an ANSI/ISO format that is unambiguous.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to store multiple values in the same row.

While you could bundle up the data into your own data structure which is opaque to the DBMS this is very bad practice. Its also very bad practice to have multiple tables with the same structure.

You can represent the data simply by using multiple rows to represent each record:

```
CREATE table multid (
   userid integer,
   rdate date,
   value varchar(20)
   PRIMARY KEY (userid, rdate, value)
);
```

You can then extract the data as per your desired format with:

```
SELECT rdate, GROUP_CONCAT(value SEPARATOR ';')
FROM multid
WHERE userid='user 1'
GROUP BY rdate;
```

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I was not meaning that the values were on the same row. This was my way of showing columns. In the actual application they would not be delimited with a ;